# How to make a image when mOver(obj) is called

Tags: javascript

i want to show image when mOver(obj) is called:

```
<script>
function mOver(obj) {
    obj.innerHTML = "Thank You"
}

function mOut(obj) {
    obj.innerHTML = "Mouse Over Me"
}
</script>
```

for instance i have this image:  http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schoolscom_gray.gif

when i make so: http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schoolscom_gray.gif

```
function mOver(obj) {
        obj.innerHTML = http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schoolscom_gray.gif; 
    }
```

it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

`innerHTML` replace the content of your `obj` by a HTML representation of a `string`.
If your `obj` is a container (like a `div`) you should do this :

```
function mOver(obj) {
    obj.innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schoolscom_gray.gif" alt="..."/>'; 
}
```

If your `obj` is a `<img>` tag you should do this :

```
function mOver(obj) {
    obj.src = 'http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schoolscom_gray.gif'; 
}
```

:)